# How to enable browser cookies for cypress test case?

Tags: cookies, cypress

I'm not able to proceed with my Cypress test as I need my browser cookies enabled.
Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token')
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once